# When does $P_n \to\delta$ implies that $f *P_n \to f$ in $L^\infty(\mathbb T)$?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, dirac-delta

In the question $\mathbb T$ is a unit circle. For one example, even the continuity of $f$ does not suffice. If we let $P_n$ be the Dirichlet kernel 
$$P_n=\frac{1}{2\pi} \sum_{m=-n}^n e^{imx},$$
which goes to $\delta$ as $n\to\infty$, then one can prove that there is a continuous function whose Fourier series $P_n * f$  does not converge uniformly(even pointwise in a dense subset of $\mathbb T$) to $f$. Then what additional condition is needed to the question?

Comment: This is just a complicated way of asking "when does a Fourier series converge uniformly?" This is a classical question and you can find some insight [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series), for a start.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Oh, I am asking for general $P_n$ that converges to $\delta$. The Dirichlet kernel is just one example.

Comment: The dense subset of $\mathbb{T}$ on which $P_n * f$ does not converge, is that a null-set?